# Jframe Program giving NoClassDefFoundError on run

Tags: java, exception, jframe, jlabel

My Code

```
import java.awt.*; 
 import javax.swing.*; 

 // Create a simple GUI window
 public class TopLevelWindow {

    private static void createWindow() {

       //Create and set up the window. 
       JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple GUI");
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

       JLabel textLabel = new JLabel("I'm a label in the window",SwingConstants.CENTER); 
       textLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100)); 
       frame.getContentPane().add(textLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER); 

       //Display the window. 
       frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
       frame.pack();
       frame.setVisible(true); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       createWindow();

    }
 }
```

And how i run the program with the exceptions are
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.` rather than `/` to specify the fully qualified class name when using `java`

```
java java1.TopLevelWindow
```

Also add a package declaration:

```
package java1;
```

Comment: You have no package declaration in your class. Add it and your original `java` command will work

Comment: @Ankit I think you might like to have a read through [Packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/)